# Store bean instance in Spring

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-mvc, spring-webflow

I have an authenticating method in my web application, which gets a http parameter from another application. I load my user from the database and store it in a spring bean. In my login controller it is instantiated, but when I inject it in another controller, it losts its properties and I get 'null' when I want to reach my user. How can I make a bean's property available in all other controller? I don't want to use static properties... I tried to make the bean 'session scoped', but it doesn't work.

The suerBean:

```
    @Service
@SessionScoped
public class SessionUserBean {

    public Dolgozo user;

    public Boolean userIsDolgozo;
    public Boolean userIsIranyito;
    public Boolean userIsVezeto;
    public Boolean userIsOsztalyVezeto;


    public void setUser(Dolgozo user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public Dolgozo getUser() {
        return user;
    }
}
```

I set the value of the user property:

```
@Autowired
    private SessionUser sessionUser;
    @Autowired
    private SessionUserBean user;

    @Autowired
    private HttpServletRequest request;

    @RequestMapping("index.htm")
    public String doLogin(@RequestParam String token) {


        if (login.isUserAuthanticated(token)) {

            user.setUser(sessionUser.getDolgozo()); 

            return "sikeresBelepes";
        }

        return "sikertelenBelepes";
    }
```

And this is where I want to use it:

```
@Autowired
    private SessionUserBean user;

    public void setUp() {
        employees = drp.findByCsoportID(user.getUser().getCsoportid().getId());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What a mess!

Why not use [Spring Security](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/)? It automatically manages [Security Context](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/context/SecurityContext.html) for you by setting up a set of filters. And you have access to user information in any place of your app.

If no, you must set up your user in session somewhere in your code, you cannot just autowire it. Like this:

```
@RequestMapping("index.htm")
public String doLogin(@RequestParam String token) {
    if (login.isUserAuthanticated(token)) {
        user.setUser(sessionUser.getDolgozo()); 
        return "sikeresBelepes";

       session.addAttribute("securityUser", user);
    }

    return "sikertelenBelepes";
}
```

and then get it from session with `getAttribute()`

Comment: It's OK, that I can store the user info in the Security Context, but if I have e.g. 10 users, who are using the system in the same time, how can I idetentify each one? My opinion was, that I can idenetify them by their own session. I managed to do this, by allowing a bean to become session bean. It almost works, but there are still problems. There are situations when the application messes up the users, and allowing simple users to see and control things, that just managers should see.

Comment: If you have 10 users you'll have 10 different sessions for each of them. And Spring works great with multi-user applications. Without any problems. In your case you should check your own code.